# "doch" oder "aber"

Tags: grammar

Wie kann man wissen, ob man "doch" oder "aber" benutzen soll? Die beiden Begriffe drücken einen Gegensatz aus.

> Ich studiere in Münster, aber mein Bruder studiert in Berlin.
>   Wir rennen auf den Bahnsteig, doch der Zug ist schon abgefahren.

Answer (score 8):

Das ist Geschmacksache. Die beiden Wörter sind austauschbar. Folgende Sätze sind ebenfalls korrekt und stilistisch in Ordnung:

> Ich studiere in Münster, doch mein Bruder studiert in Berlin.
>   Wir rennen auf den Bahnsteig, aber der Zug ist schon abgefahren.

Comment: könnest du ein "in diesem Kontext" vor "austauschbar" einfügen? Nur zur Sicherheit. Internet, Leute lesen nicht alles :)

Comment: Inwiefern ist das kontextabhängig? Hier handelt es sich mE um echte Synonyme.

Comment: Ich stimme mit Ingmar überein. Mir fällt kein Kontext ein, in dem die beiden Wörter nicht austauschbar wären. Ich werde daher meine Antwort nicht verändern.

Comment: *Doch*, wirst Du. :P